# converting url to regex only username and password of the url

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

can someone please show me how convert only the username and the password of a link with regex ??

```
link = 'http://test.ddns.net:8000/get.php?username=9OsSVedOky&password=Oz2Vmx9GuW&type=list&output=tr'
url = 'http://test.ddns.net:8000/get.php?username=[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|&password=[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|&type=list&output=tr'
urls = re.findall(url, link)`
```

sorry if i'm not using the right terms but i'm new to coding .

thank you

Comment: So new that you can't show what code you tried to do this with?

Comment: Does it have to be regex? You could use [`urllib.parse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs).

Comment: link = 'http://test.ddns.net:8000/get.php?username=9OsSVedOky&password=Oz2Vmx9GuW&type=list&output=tr'

url = 'http://test.ddns.net:8000/get.php?username=[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|&password=[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|&type=list&output=tr'



urls = re.findall(url, link)  


this is what i've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing a url with a regex is in general a bad idea, and especially bad when you have such a poor grasp of the syntax. If you *must* do it (and the only good reason is because you have been told to), then

```
>>> import re
>>> rx=re.compile(r"username=(?P<username>[^&]+).*password=(?P<password>[^&]+)")
>>> m = rx.search(link)
>>> m.groupdict()['username']
'9OsSVedOky'
>>> m.groupdict()['password']
'Oz2Vmx9GuW'
```

But I endorse Rawing's suggestion. It's much better:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> qsp=urllib.parse.parse_qs(link.partition('?')[2])
>>> qsp['username']
['9OsSVedOky']
>>> qsp['password']
['Oz2Vmx9GuW']
```

Comment: Isn't it possible the password is before the username ?

Comment: Yes, it is. That is one of the reasons a regex is a bad idea. Coping with that sort of variation gets complicated very quickly. On the other hand, even though the password *can* be first, it almost never is. But split the regex into two (at `.*`) and search the link twice if you like.

Comment: I did tell you not to use one.

Comment: I wouldn't give you pointers, just saying regex is used in all kinds of parsing including decent parsers.

Comment: Why use a general-purpose parser when there are very good special-purpose parsers designed for precisely what you are trying to do?

Comment: the problem is that i will have a lot of links with different usernames and password. i want to extract the link with username and password of each user.

Comment: And what can a regex do to split out the userid and password that `urllib.parse.parse_qs()` cannot?

Comment: So, what you are saying is, `urllib.parse.parse_qs()` does in fact do exactly what you want, but you still choose to roll your own. If this is a personal project, I suppose it's up to you, but using `urllib` tools gives more readable code, is more maintainable, and is more robust. In a code review I would tell you, as I did at the beginning, *don't use a regex.* If your grasp of regular expressions is so poor that you have to ask for help on SO with a simple problem, why are you so determined to use one when the best advice we can give you is *don't*?